# C# MongoDB driver trouble( NORM)

Tags: mongodb, drivers, norm

I have used NORM driver in production. New year holidays - it is pretty cool, so my project get high loading and i want to set up a replication set, but have a problem - Norm does not support replication set :( . as far as i understand sharding too?

Help me :) Who did use mongodb csharp or official 10gen driver with replset? Is there any problem on production? If i choose another driver I'll have to rewrite the repository, but I do not want it to be in vain. Is there some issues?

Answer (score 1):

Sharding should not depend on driver-specific support. When you shard, you connect to a router application `mongos` and this router behaves exactly like mongod.

So you *should* be able to shard. But you will probably need to change the "connection string". The suggested setup is to have one `mongos` per application server (instead of your current single `mongod`).